# Override OnPaint-Event TBCDProgressBar

Tags: delphi, pascal, freepascal

I want to override the `OnPaint`-Event of the [TBCDProgressBar Component](http://wiki.freepascal.org/BGRAControls#TBCDProgressBar). It's a component for Lazarus (*freepascal*), I tagged Delphi on purpose because there are no differences when overriding events, and I want as much help as I can get.

`TBCDProgressBar` has no `OnPaint` event in its decleration:

```
  TBCDProgressBar = class(TCDProgressBar)
  private
    FBCThemeManager: TBCThemeManager;
    procedure SetFBCThemeManager(AValue: TBCThemeManager);
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  published
    property ThemeManager: TBCThemeManager read FBCThemeManager write SetFBCThemeManager;
  end;
```

My first approach was to trace down `TBCDProgressBar` until I would find the `OnPaint`-Event.

Result was:

- `TCDProgressBar = class(TCDControl)`
- `TCDControl = class(TCustomControl)`
- `TCustomControl = class(TWinControl)`

And finally in `TCustomControl` I found `property OnPaint: TNotifyEvent read FOnPaint write FOnPaint;`

I don't understand how I can override `OnPaint` from  `TCustomControl` so that it affects the `TBCDProgressBar`.

Edit://

I didn't know you can override it as usual, so here is the solution for anyone having the same problem:

```
TBCDProgressBarWithOnPaint = class(TBCDProgressBar)
protected
  procedure Paint; override;
end; 

procedure TBCDProgressBarWithOnPaint.Paint;
begin
  inherited;

  // drawing a line on Progressbar
  Canvas.Pen.Color:=clRed;
  Canvas.Line(200,0,200,20);
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is visible (protected, public or published) and virtual, then you can override it no matter how far up the tree it is, just as if it were declared in TProgressBar.